# ¿Cómo desaparecer un formulario al momento de hacer submit en MVC.Net?

Tags: c#, mvc

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en MVC.Net en dónde dentro de mi vista muestro tres cosas. La primera de ellas, tres tarjetas informativas con su respectiva información (información de una BBDD), un gráfico lineal y un formulario dónde yo enviaré como parámetros cierta información. Todo esta funcional, relacionado a diversos Procedimientos Almacenados.

Adjuntaré parte de mi vista en dónde tengo el formulario:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Lineas", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Linea">Línea:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Linea" name="Linea">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Mes">Mes:</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="Mes" name="Mes">
                            <option value="1">Enero</option>
                            <option value="2">Febrero</option>
                            <option value="3">Marzo</option>
                            <option value="4">Abril</option>
                            <option value="5">Mayo</option>
                            <option value="6">Junio</option>
                            <option value="7">Julio</option>
                            <option value="8">Agosto</option>
                            <option value="9">Septiembre</option>
                            <option value="10">Octubre</option>
                            <option value="11">Noviembre</option>
                            <option value="12">Diciembre</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Año">Año:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Año" name="Año">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Obtener Datos</button>
                </div>
                if (Model != null)
                {
                    foreach(var item in Model)
                    {
                        <p>Linea: @item.Linea</p>
                        <p>Mes Anterior: @item.MesAnterior</p>
                        <p>Mes Actual: @item.MesActual</p>
                        <p>Diferencia: @item.Diferencia</p>
                        <p>Tolerancia: @item.Tolerancia</p>
                    }
                }
            }
```

Adjunto el método de mi HomeController:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Lineas(string Linea, int Mes, int Año)
    {

        using (OpexDB db = new OpexDB())
        {
            var lineas = db.Database.SqlQuery<Lineas>("SP_NIVELES @NIVEL, @MES, @AÑO",
                                                                new SqlParameter("NIVEL", Linea),
                                                                new SqlParameter("MES", Mes),
                                                                new SqlParameter("AÑO", Año)).ToList();

            return View("Index", lineas);
        }
    }
```

Y adjunto mi modelo:

```
public class Lineas
{
    public string Linea { get; set; }
    public decimal MesAnterior { get; set; }
    public decimal MesActual { get; set; }
    public decimal Diferencia { get; set; }
    public decimal Tolerancia { get; set; }
}
```

Me gustaría saber como puedo hacer para que al presionar el submit, desaparezca el contenido del formulario dentro de mi vista y en su lugar aparezca únicamente lo que yo estoy mostrando dentro de mi foreach que son los datos que estoy mostrando.

Comment: if (Model == null) no resulta?

Comment: No resulta. Lo tengo en (Model != null) para que el contenido que recorro dentro del foreach se muestre al ejecutar el submit. Lo que busco es que al salir lo que tengo dentro del foreach(hacer el submit) desaparezca el formulario que tengo al principio.

Comment: Entiendo en que al inicio Model es igual null, ahí se muestra el form y el foreach se oculta. Tú haces el submit, y Model es distinto a null, por lo que ahora si se muestra el foreach. Lo que yo te digo (es que si funciona así el asunto) es que pongas `if (Model == null) ` en el form, así no lo muestra cuando vuelve del post con un model cargado

Comment: Efectivamente, es así como sugieres. Te agradezco. Aunque al hacer esto, (no se porque) se desapareció el contenido que tenía en mis tarjetas en un principio. Estas las muestro a través de un ViewData, ¿afectará el return View("Index", lineas) que muestro en mi controller para que ya no se muestren?

Comment: Seguramente el `if` está tomando también las tarjetas. Sobre si `View("Index", lineas)` afecta, claro que sí. `lineas` en la vista pasa a ser `Model`, por lo tanto si tu envías un objeto distinto de null, afectará en los if que pones como por ejemplo `if(Model!=null)`